# How to format the url?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to format url. Here is an example:

Input:

```
www.google.com
```

or

```
google.com
```

Output:

```
https://www.google.com/
```

I need to format the url because I'm using a `validator` function that needs to check if the text is a url. When I type `www.google.com` or `google.com` it says it's not a url because it requires `https` at the beginning of the text.

My code:

```dart
validator: (value) {
  if (value == null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (Uri.parse(value).host.isEmpty) {
    return "Please type a valid url";
  }
},
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How to format the url? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some more conditions to your validator function :

```
validator: (value) => {
  if (value == null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (!value.startsWith("https://")) {
    value = "https://" + value;
  }
  if (!value.startsWith("https://www.") && !value.startsWith("https://")) {
    value = "https://www." + value.substring(8);
  }
  if (Uri.parse(value).host.isEmpty) {
    return "Please type a valid url";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! The `String` type has no method `slice`.

Comment: My bad, Javascript on my mind. Now check

Comment: It doesn't matter

Comment: Your code works! You solved a huge problem for me! Thanks again!

Comment: This would incorrectly prefix non-http/https URLs, and the `(!value.startsWith("https://www.") && !value.startsWith("https://"))` check is wrong.  You shouldn't be adding a `www.` subdomain anyway; `https://example.com/` and `https://www.example.com/` are not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would first sanitize the URL with something like:

```dart
String ensureScheme(String url) {
  var uri = Uri.tryParse(url);
  if (uri == null || !uri.hasScheme) {
    url = 'https://$url';
  }
  return url;
}
```

which would add an `https` URL scheme only if no scheme is already present, thereby avoiding mangling URLs that use other schemes (e.g. `file:///some/path`, `mailto:user@example.com`, `ssh://user@host.example.com`, `tel:+1-800-555-1212`).

Additionally, note that your `Uri.parse(value).host.isEmpty` check is not quite correct:

- `Uri.parse` will throw an exception if given unparsable input (e.g. `':'`).  You probably should be using `Uri.tryParse` instead.
- An empty host does not necessarily imply an invalid URL.  For example, all of the following would have an empty host:

  - `file:///some/path`
  - `mailto:user@example.com`
  - `tel:+1-800-555-1212`

  (But maybe that's okay if you don't care about such URLs.)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Can you share the code of the validator method? I don't know how to add your code to the validator method

Comment: @MyCar Your question title asks how to *format* an URL, not how to *validate* it.  You'd just call `ensureScheme` on the URL to sanitize it first, before trying to validate it with whatever method you want.  So, for example, you perhaps could check whether `Uri.tryParse(ensureScheme(value))` is `null` (although doing so would accept the other types of URLs I mentioned).

Comment: Is the code you said like this: https://pastebin.com/KxfkJ6Xt